# Prototypes on Custom Elements

Tags: javascript, html, prototype

Suppose I have a custom HTML element tag `<custom-table>` with an attribute `tableVal="10"`.

I would like to easily fetch the `tableVal` without using `.getAttribute()` *(since I'm creating a public API that is easy-to-use)*.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
var customElement = document.querySelector('custom-table');
console.log(customElement.val)
```

Output: `undefined`
Expected Output: `10`

This is my current try:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(customElements.prototype, val.prototype)
function val(){
    return this.getAttribute("tableVal")
}
```

Any idea or approaches through which I can achieve this?

Comment: how are you declaring/registering your custom web component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this (see the [MDN documentation on writing custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)), but one is to create a class for your custom element with an accessor `val` property, and use that class when registering your custom element:

```js
class CustomTable extends HTMLElement {
    get val() {
        return this.getAttribute("tableVal");
    }
}
customElements.define("custom-table", CustomTable);
```

Live Example:

```html
<!-- Defining the custom element -->
<script>
class CustomTable extends HTMLElement {
    get val() {
        return this.getAttribute("tableVal");
    }
}
customElements.define("custom-table", CustomTable);
</script>

<!-- Using it in HTML -->
<custom-table tableVal="10"></custom-table>

<!-- Testing the property -->
<script>
const table = document.querySelector("custom-table");
console.log(table.val); // 10
</script>
```